# Integral solution to a³+3ab²=4c³

Tags: polynomials, integers

Please help if **integral solutions** to this equation exists or not

**A³+3AB²=4C³**

Such that A,B,C are disninct
I thought we may be possible to prove solutions exists if and only if A=B=C condition is satisfied.

Comment: $A=1,\;B=-1,\;C=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$(A-B)^3=A^3-3A^2B+3AB^2-B^3 \\
(A+B)^3=A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$$

This gives
$$A^3+3AB^2= \frac{1}{2} \left((A+B)^3+(A-B)^3 \right)$$

Therefore, if you have a solution
$$(A-B)^3+(A+B)^3=(2C)^3$$
Use FLT to deduce that all solutions satisfy $A=B$ or $A=-B$ or $A=0$.